# SQL Returning Count + other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following SQL query : `"SELECT * FROM  table WHERE id = '$geo_name_id' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET $offset"`

This works fine, but now I want to also return the amount of rows in the whole table `WHERE id = 'geo_name_id` (without the limit). I have tried something like this :

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as totalExpectedItems, * FROM  story_img_vid WHERE id = '$geo_name_id' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET $offset"
```

However this doesn't seem to work as expected as it only returns one row.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery :

```
"SELECT t.*,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
         WHERE id = '$geo_name_id') as cnt
  FROM  table t
  WHERE t.id = '$geo_name_id'
  ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC
  LIMIT 10 OFFSET $offset"
```

`cnt` Column will contain the count.

Or a join to a derived table:

```
"SELECT t.*,
        t2.cnt
 FROM table t
 JOIN(SELECT s.id,count(*) as cnt
      FROM table s GROUP BY s.id) t2
  ON(t.id = t2.id)
WHERE t.id = '$geo_name_id'
ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET $offset"
```

Comment: Could you just explain what `t.*` does, that's the only part I find confusing

Comment: Its an alias, each time you want to call `table` instead of write `table.Column` you can write `t.column` . So `t.*` is like `*` only from `table`

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot, I'll accept your answer when it allows me in 10 mins :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as totalExpectedItems, * FROM  story_img_vid WHERE id = '$geo_name_id'"
```